# Выделить ячейки в GridView

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать При нажатии на GridView подсветить ее и изьять информацию?

Answer (score 0):

Выделяет и проверяет,нажата ли она уже и нажата ли ячейка с цифрой.

```
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            boolean flag = parent.getItemAtPosition (position).toString ().matches ("[-+]?\\d+");
            int number = flag? Integer.parseInt (parent.getItemAtPosition (position).toString ()):0;

            if(flag && number>=1?true:false && flag && number<=quantityDayl? true : false)
           if(((ColorDrawable)(Drawable)view.getBackground ()).getColor () == Color.RED){
               view.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor("#7d74ec"));
               edSumma.setText (String.valueOf (Double.parseDouble (edSumma.getText ().toString ()) - quantity));


           }

           else {
               view.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED);
               edSumma.setText (String.valueOf (Double.parseDouble (edSumma.getText ().toString ()) + quantity));
           }
           else{}
        }

    });
```